# Sender class - GCM Example - Java App engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I use the google example (gcm-demo-appengine - [Google Demo](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html))

but i think there may be some problems with google source code, when i run it, it throws

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android/gcm/server/Sender
>   
> at cloud.spam.filter.server.SendMessageServlet.newSender(SendMessageServlet.java:63)
>   
> at cloud.spam.filter.server.SendMessageServlet.init(SendMessageServlet.java:54)

There is some problems with the sender class (seriously?)

Can we replace sender class with something else? This is the first time I use GCM thus I have no idea how important sender class is and what it is used for.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your gcm-server.jar is in the war/WEB-INF/lib folder of your project. Nothing else will do

Answer (score 0):

Sender needs the lib for JSON operation. In my case, Just put a json-simple-1.1.1.jar file in war/WEB-INF/lib and set the jar path as reference. Finally the NoClassDefFoundError issue been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just clean the project make sure you have included json-simple-1.1.1.jar as well. If it does not work, add the jar files to libraries in java build path and clean the project.